# i can not download kivy by pip and i get an error exception

Tags: python, android, module, kivy

I have tried to download kivy a lot of times. Sometimes it reaches almost the finish, and then I get the error. And sometimes, from the start, I got that error.

Please help me. I can not describe more if one of you has faced that problem before.

[image: 1]

I have tried a lot of times.

[image: 2]

```
Collecting kivy
  Downloading Kivy-2.0.0.tar.gz (23.7 MB)
     |██                              | 1.5 MB 6.9 kB/s eta 0:53:31ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 438, in _error_catcher
    yield
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 519, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt) if not fp_closed else b""
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\cachecontrol\filewrapper.py", line 62, in read
    data = self.__fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\http\client.py", line 464, in read
    s = self.fp.read(amt)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1273, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1129, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
TimeoutError: The read operation timed out

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 164, in exc_logging_wrapper
    status = run_func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 205, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 338, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 92, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 482, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 349, in resolve
    self._add_to_criteria(self.state.criteria, r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 173, in _add_to_criteria
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 151, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 155, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 47, in _iter_built
    candidate = func()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 201, in _make_candidate_from_link
    self._link_candidate_cache[link] = LinkCandidate(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 281, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 156, in __init__
    self.dist = self._prepare()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 225, in _prepare
    dist = self._prepare_distribution()
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\candidates.py", line 292, in _prepare_distribution
    return preparer.prepare_linked_requirement(self._ireq, parallel_builds=True)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 482, in prepare_linked_requirement
    return self._prepare_linked_requirement(req, parallel_builds)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 527, in _prepare_linked_requirement
    local_file = unpack_url(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 213, in unpack_url
    file = get_http_url(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\operations\prepare.py", line 94, in get_http_url
    from_path, content_type = download(link, temp_dir.path)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\download.py", line 145, in __call__
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\progress_bars.py", line 144, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\network\utils.py", line 63, in response_chunks
    for chunk in response.raw.stream(
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 576, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 512, in read
    with self._error_catcher():
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\contextlib.py", line 153, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(typ, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\urllib3\response.py", line 443, in _error_catcher
    raise ReadTimeoutError(self._pool, None, "Read timed out.")
pip._vendor.urllib3.exceptions.ReadTimeoutError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Read timed out.[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

It happen because of lost of internet connection during downloading

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).